# Retrieving a key and value from a dictionary not finding value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary which looks like this:

```py
{1: {'10:00 11:00': ['35,Piano']}, 2: {'10:00 11:00': ['39,Piano']}, 3: {'8:45 9:15': ['88,Piano'], '9:15 9:45': ['89,Piano'], '9:45 10:15': ['99,Piano']}, 4: {'9:00 9:30': ['100,Piano', '117,Piano'], '9:30 10:00': ['124,Piano'], '10:00 10:30': ['125,Piano'], '10:30 11:00': ['126,Piano'], '11:00 11:30': ['127,Piano']}, 5: {'9:00 9:30': ['128,Piano'], '9:30 10:00': ['129,Piano'], '10:00 10:30': ['130,Piano'], '10:30 11:00': ['131,Piano']}}
```

It is retrieved via an SQL query as a string and converted by ast.literal_eval()

I am trying to retrieve all values for each time slot, but it doesn't find it.

```
days_in_current_timetable = [1,2,3,4,5]

for x in days_in_current_timetable:
    
    # data is retrieved from an SQL query as a string so used ast.literal_eval() to convert
    self.sterilised_list = ast.literal_eval(raw_data[1]) 
 
    print("This is The Dictionary: ", sterilised_list)

    for slot in self.sterilised_list.values():
        for key in slot:
            print("This is the key:", key)
            print("This is the value: ", sterilised_list.get(key, "Not Found"))
```

Here is an example of the output:

```
This is The Dictionary:  {1: {'10:00 11:00': ['35,Piano']}, 2: {'10:00 11:00': ['39,Piano']}, 3: {'8:45 9:15': ['88,Piano'], '9:15 9:45': ['89,Piano'], '9:45 10:15': ['99,Piano']}, 4: {'9:00 9:30': ['100,Piano', '117,Piano'], '9:30 10:00': ['124,Piano'], '10:00 10:30': ['125,Piano'], '10:30 11:00': ['126,Piano'], '11:00 11:30': ['127,Piano']}, 5: {'9:00 9:30': ['128,Piano'], '9:30 10:00': ['129,Piano'], '10:00 10:30': ['130,Piano'], '10:30 11:00': ['131,Piano']}}
This is the key: 10:00 11:00
This is the value:  Not Found
```

How should I properly retrieve '35,Piano', or any of the other values?

Comment: Can you make this a [mre], please? Include the required data in the code, so that everyone of us can run and reproduce it

Comment: `sterilised_list.get(key, "Not Found")` should be `slot.get(key, "Not Found")`. The original list does not contain the keys present in the dictionaries iterated over in the outer loop.

Comment: Thanks so much. It is obvious now I know!

Answer (score 1):

1. `sterilised_list` should be `self.sterilised_list`
2. don't call a dictionary a list. It's confusing
3. `key` is not a key of `sterilised_list`, but a key of `slot`

Change the last line to

```py
print("This is the value: ", slot.get(key, "Not Found"))
```

[Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (with `self` stuff removed):

```py
sterilised_dict = {1: {'10:00 11:00': ['35,Piano']}, 2: {'10:00 11:00': ['39,Piano']}, 3: {'8:45 9:15': ['88,Piano'], '9:15 9:45': ['89,Piano'], '9:45 10:15': ['99,Piano']}, 4: {'9:00 9:30': ['100,Piano', '117,Piano'], '9:30 10:00': ['124,Piano'], '10:00 10:30': ['125,Piano'], '10:30 11:00': ['126,Piano'], '11:00 11:30': ['127,Piano']}, 5: {'9:00 9:30': ['128,Piano'], '9:30 10:00': ['129,Piano'], '10:00 10:30': ['130,Piano'], '10:30 11:00': ['131,Piano']}}
print("This is The Dictionary: ", sterilised_dict)
for slot in sterilised_dict.values():
    for key in slot:
        print("This is the key:", key)
        print("This is the value: ", slot.get(key, "Not Found"))
```

Comment: Thanks. That makes perfect sense. I am really new to Python and Dictionaries, having only really used PHP and arrays before, it is a bit of a learning curve.